# Asymptotic behaviour of the sequence of the number of groups of order $n$

Tags: group-theory

Let $f(n) = \text{# of groups of order} \ n$. I want to study the asymptotic behaviour of this sequence as $n \to \infty$. Clearly $\lim \inf f(n) = 1$ and $\lim \sup f(n) = \infty$, so the sequence is jumping around.

I'm wondering if there exists a "nice" function $g$ such that $$0<\limsup_{n \to +\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}<+\infty$$

Comment: I think such precise knowledge of the asymptotics of $f(n)$ is an open question.

Comment: A very interesting survey is given in: John H. Conway, Heiko Dietrich and E.A. O’Brien $\textit{Counting groups: gnus, moas and other exotica}$.

Answer (score 3):

It may really depend on the prime factorization of $n$. For example, you can see [here](http://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_groups_of_order_n) that there's a large gap between the number of groups of order $2^{k} - 1$ and $2^{k}$. 
However, there's an asymptotic formula for the number of groups of order $p^{n}$ for a fixed prime $p$:
$$
f(n, p) = p^{(2/27 + o(1))n^{3}}.
$$
See [Higman-Sims asymptotic formula](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Higman-Sims_asymptotic_formula_on_number_of_groups_of_prime_power_order).